# Android informations to report on a bug report

Tags: android, email, report

I want to add a Bug Report/Report Problem option to my app, which sends device and app info and a user's comment to the developer. I was wondering if there are any "standard" things to report? I am reporting OS Version, Device Name and App Version. Is there anything important I'm missing out and should include? What are you guys normally including ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the free service

http://www.crashlytics.com/

you can get the features what is mentioned above.

Comment: I know there are many libraries to to the work for you, but I wan't to do it myself :)

Comment: sorry i don't know about doing it on our own.

Comment: I don't want to make a crash report, I just want to add a function where users can report a bug they found, and I want to include some device info to make finding the problem easier, and I asked which infos to include

Comment: so far as per understanding of your requirement, Create a feedback option in your menu--> settings--> feedback like this and Create a layout as per your wish. keep a edittext for the user to enter their feedbacks. and get the device information from [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3236201/2811343) codings. and get the informations in a package or file, keep a sent as mail link , then you will receive the infos as mail. if you want to do it manually then you can proceed like this. (use email intent like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8893336/2811343))

Comment: glad my answer helped you. you can accept my answer if you find it helped you.

Comment: Sorry forgot to do that :)

Comment: glad my answer helped u! :)

Answer (score 5):

You could avoid sending out this data manually by integrating with a service like [Instabug](http://instabug.com)

which allows the user to report bugs through your preferred method, but mainly through shaking the device.
It will display a screenshot of the current view that the user can draw on for visual bug identification. What gets reported along is (but not only) the following:

- App version
- Device type
- OS version
- Location
- CPU load
- Memory usage
- Storage
- Connectivity
- Battery
- Orientation
- Network and console logs
- Visual reproduction steps
- UI view hierarchy inspection

users can further describe the bug using text, extra screenshots, voice notes, or screen recordings.

All reports arrive in your Instabug dashboard containing various details such as:

- Network and console logs
- Complete Device details
- Reproduction steps
- Crash stack trace (In case of a crash report)

It only takes a line of code to integrate.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Comment: but it's too expensive