# Android open the native email dialog when the user taps the email address

Tags: android

I have a TextView on my UI with the email of the user. How is it possible to open ​the android ​native ​email ​dialog ​when ​the ​user ​taps ​the ​email ​address and put the email address clicked to senders?

Comment: What is the mean of android native email dialog. Can you add some pics?

Comment: native email app in android, or any email app, and add the clicked email address to receiver

Comment: Do you want something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893336/1640009

Comment: yes! thank you very much! I will try it now